# Android studio lock icon on files

Tags: android, jar

Can any one help resolve this. Iv added a jar file to my android project

Right click of the jar and selected "Add as library"

But the classes in the jar show lock icons and I cant import them...

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mine show lock icons and they have been imported correctly. Did you add this to your build.gradle file?

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-stream-4.0.1.jar')
}
```

also once version 4.0.1 is in maven central (soon? https://twitter.com/t4j_news/status/445971905191759874) you can simply import it by adding `compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-stream:4.0.1'` without including the jar file at all.

Comment: Actually it can find the classes but when I try an compile...I get a load of error and the lock sign is still there:(:(

Comment: maybe try using the version that is in maven central to see if that works? change the compile statement to `compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-stream:3.0.5'`