# Lock Icon on Android Studio files

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have just added a jar in android studio by pasting it in the libs folder and adding it as a library. Moreover it does show the jar added in build.gradle file and I am able to import the files however I am not able to edit those files as they have a lock icon on those files. I have tried setting permissions to that folder to full control for all users and I have even tried [Android studio lock icon on files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673757/android-studio-lock-icon-on-files)
but nothing helped...Any suggestions to get this working will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the bottom-right corner of Android Studio window (version 1.2), there is a padlock icon.
You can click it to toggle between lock/unlock of the currently open file.

I hope that helps someone.

I am not yet legible to adding images to answers on SO. But with the directions above, you should see the padlock icon.

Comment: Is the file you mean to unlock/lock open in android studio when you reach for the lock/unlock icon? Make sure you at least have one open file. Otherwise, the icon will be disabled.

Comment: my drawable folder is locked :(

Comment: I am encountering the same problem, i have added a library

Comment: @faisal1208 In most editors, jar ( library ) files are readonly. However see if this link can help you achieve what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40698957/my-jar-resource-files-in-intellij-are-read-only-and-i-need-to-edit-them

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had somehow accidentally changed permissions for my files . There was only read permission in the files . So i checked the permissions by **ls -l** . Then changed the permissions to read,write,execute by **chmod 775** by logging into root. Then restarted Android Studio and it WORKED !!!